# I am programming in j2me, I need to write text with rich format for a help screen

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, mobile-phones

I am programming a J2me application. I have the menu with an option of Help.

For this screen I need to present a text that includes some bold words, italics etc...

Which is the best option?

My first solution:

```
StringItem messageItem = new StringItem("","");
messageItem.setText("lorem ipsum etc etc...");
messageItem.setFont(Font.getFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM,Font.STYLE_BOLD,Font.SIZE_MEDIUM)); 
append(messageItem);
```

And then add another new StringItem with another font style:

```
    StringItem messageItem2 = new StringItem("","");
...
 append(messageItem2);
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler option: http://www.j2mehtml.com/

Comment: Do you know if the text it produces are readable by screen readers? If it uses Canvas, it is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is using external UI library such as LWUIT.

Please see this:
http://www.nextgenmoco.com/2010/02/mobile-web-and-html-inside-javame-with.html

Comment: I would like a simpler solution, this is a whole framework, thx.